# How can you use a request.user in model form in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to be able to use the request.user in the model form init. Here is my view:

```
def create(request, pk):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            object = form.save()
            object.save()
            return render(request, 'going_create.html', {'object':object})
    else:
        form = CreateForm()
    return render(request, 'being_create.html', {'form':form})
```

Basically, I need request.user to prefill a django form field. Here is my form:

```
class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        super(CreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['first_name'].initial = self.request.user.first_name

    class Meta:
        model = creater
        fields = (
            'first_name',
        )
```

Also, there are `form = CreateForm(request.POST)` if request.method == 'POST', and `form = CreateForm()` when else. So, as I am not familiar with using a function view, I hope you could tell me where I need to add the code so that I could use request.user to prefill a django field. Thank you, and please leave any questions you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass it though a parameter:

```
class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
        super(CreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            self.fields['first_name'].initial = user.first_name

    class Meta:
        model = creater
        fields = (
            'first_name',
        )
```

In the view you then construct the form with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def create(request, pk):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            object = form.save()
            return render(request, 'going_create.html', {'object':object})
    else:
        form = CreateForm(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'being_create.html', {'form':form})
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: Thank you, but my code doesn't seem to work. Could it be the fact that you wrote `user=None` in the `def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):`?

Comment: @codebuilder: you need to pass the `user=request.user` in the view. A form is (by default) request unaware, so you need to pass the user of the request to the form.